# Convert date string to datetime for whole column of df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

```
df = pd.read_csv('bitcoin.csv')
print(df)
```

gives

```
      Date          Open     High     Low      Close    Volume  
0     Apr 16, 2018  8337.57  8371.15  7925.73  8058.67  5,631,310,000   
1     Apr 15, 2018  7999.33  8338.42  7999.33  8329.11  5,244,480,000  ....
```

I tried

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['Date']), format = '%b %d, %Y')
```

but got

TypeError: Unrecognized value type:  && ValueError: time data 'Date' does not match format '%b %d %Y' (match)

I also tried

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d, %Y')
```

but got SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

when running

```
print(df['Date'])
```

after printing it says

```
Name: Date, Length: 1567, dtype: object
```

Not sure whats going on here? Is it already a datetime object?

Comment: Add `pd.to_datetime(... errors='coerce')`

Comment: I can't replicate your error. `pd.to_datetime(s, format='%b %d, %Y')` works fine. Either coerce errors as per coldspeed's suggestion. Or show us some data which fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing an extra parenthesis at the end here:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d, %Y'))
```

I would suggest you do something like this, adding to @COLDSPEED comment:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%b %d, %Y', errors = 'coerce'))
```

Comment: Super embarrassed to admit it was the parenthesis,

Name: Date, Length: 1567, dtype: datetime64[ns] is the result

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y')
```

**Output**

```
0  Apr  16,    Jan 01, 1970
1  Apr  15,    Jan 01, 1970
Name: Date, dtype: object
```